# Linq extension methods that compile to store methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a code-first EF database where objects have "statuses" to track history. They're implemented something like this:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        this.Statuses = new HashSet<Status>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset SetOn { get; set; }
    public string SetBy { get; set; }
}
```

We have a few instances in code where we need to get either the oldest or newest status. Currently we've been using chained linq expressions like the following:

```
var setBy = example.Statuses.OrderByDescending(s => s.SetOn).FirstOrDefault().SetBy;
```

I think it would be more readable if we could do some of that with extensions, since getting the newest or oldest status is just a difference of whether it's sorted by ascending or descending.

A simple extension method like this works with linq-to-objects, if we've already gotten results from the database:

```
public static Status Newest(this IQueryable<Status> items)
{
    return items.OrderByDescending(s => s.SetOn).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However, this doesn't work if I'm running it on an IQueryable representing our database, since EF is unable to translate it to a store expression. For instance, if "repository" below is an `IQueryable<Example>` representing Examples in a SQL backend, the following will fail:

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.Parse("4/1/2018");
var query = repository.Where(ex => ex.Statuses.Newest().SetOn > date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way I can refactor this into an extension method or expression that can be translated to a store expression?

Comment: Why are you accepting an `IEnumerable` and not an `IQueryable` if you want to work on an `IQueryable`?

Comment: Why not add a copy of this extension for `IQueryable<Status>` so you've got both cases covered

Comment: It could be IQueryable - but the EF provider is still unable to translate this to a store expression. I'll edit that example to make it clearer.

Comment: Why not have your extension method take an `Example` object?

Comment: @NetMage that's possible, but we'd still have the root problem that EF would be unable to convert it to a store expression for a linq-to-entities query.

Comment: What is the type of `example` in your `setBy` sample assignment?

Comment: @NetMage the Example class above (with an ICollection of Statuses)

Comment: To use a user-defined function in an EF query, you must use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: I'll have to play with LINQKit a bit more, I wasn't able to get that approach to work earlier.

I can see where I could use it to create a more complex expression to pass to a .Where() clause - but I haven't wrapped my head around how I'd use that to return the newest Status from a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with LINQKit by defining an expression that returns a Status from an Example, and wrapping the IQueryable with LINQKit's Expandable. Using the above classes, I could do something like

```
private Expression<Func<Example, Status>> Newest =
   e => e.Statuses.OrderByDescending(s => s.SetOn).FirstOrDefault();
```

And invoke it like

```
var results = from example in repository.AsExpandable()
   select new
   {
      Example = example,
      LatestStatus = Newest.Invoke(example)
   };
```